# Group by in subquery have a wrong scope

Tags: hive

I'm using hive 1.1.0 ,and found such a confusing error. I want to know what's the problem and how to explain this kind of problem the next time.

I met this problem,

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 2:8 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'item_id'
```

when using

```
    select 
        item_id,
        buy_num_sum_I_7days/sum(buy_num_sum_I_7days) item_buy_probability
    FROM
    (
        select 
            item_id,
            max(buy_num_sum_I_7days) buy_num_sum_I_7days
        FROM
            mytable
        where
            dt>=20210206 and dt<=20210208
        group BY
            item_id
    )tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give an empty window to `sum` because it is an aggregate function:

```
select 
    item_id,
    buy_num_sum_I_7days/(sum(buy_num_sum_I_7days) over ()) item_buy_probability
FROM
(
    select 
        item_id,
        max(buy_num_sum_I_7days) buy_num_sum_I_7days
    FROM
        mytable
    where
        dt>=20210206 and dt<=20210208
    group BY
        item_id
)tt;
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me why my `select from tt` becomes an aggregate function? And when I use `select sum(column) from table` works fine. For the optimization of sql ?

Comment: @coffee not for optimization. `sum` is an aggregate function. Whenever you use aggregate functions, you need to use `group by`, or you need to specify a window using `over`. You can't use them on their own unless you're only selecting one column using aggregate functions.